# Hibernate composite key with auto increment field for each new first part of key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, kotlin

```
//Sorry for bad Engilsh
```

I have some EmbeddedId like:

```
@Embeddable
data class Id(

        @ManyToOne
        val firstPartOfPK: SomeClass = SomeClass(),

        val number: Int = 1

) : Serializable
```

What mapping should I use in number for automatically generating keys from Hibernate like:

```
firstPartOfPK1, 1
firstPartOfPK1, 2
firstPartOfPK1, 3
firstPartOfPK1, 4

firstPartOfPK2, 1
firstPartOfPK2, 2
firstPartOfPK2, 3

firstPartOfPK3, 1
firstPartOfPK3, 2
...
```

Each firstPartOfPK_N have new number, which have autoincrement ability from 1

Comment: `firstPartOfPK` is set by you?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yes

Comment: since you want for every `firstPartOfPK` a different counter, it is best to maintain an extra table which maps `firstPartOfPK` to the counter. then you use a stored procedure which you pass `firstPartOfPK` to fetch the current/next counter and which also increments the counter

Comment: @XtremeBaumer thx